# Doubt on dividing inequalities

Tags: inequality

If for Natural numbers $x,y,z,a,b,c$, we the following results:

1. $x>y>z$
2. $a>b>c$
   Then can we say anything about $\frac{y}{b}$? Like can we say $\frac{x}{a}>\frac{y}{b}>\frac{z}{c}$?

Comment: Perhaps helpful: For $p>q>0$ and $r>s>0$, $\frac{p}{s}>\frac{q}{r}$. [In a fraction of positive values, increasing the numerator increases the value of the fraction; however, increasing the denominator decreases the value of the fraction.]

Comment: @paw88789 ok! But is the inequality in my post correct given those conditions?

Comment: If your idea worked, you could switch the roles of $a, b, c$ (to become the numerators) with $x,y,z$ (to become the denominators. But what happens if you take an inequality of fractions and then look at the reciprocals of those fractions?  (Still assuming all numerators and denominators are positive.)

Answer (score 0):

We can add & multiply the given InEqualites.
We can not subtract & Divide them.

**Addition & Multiplication :**
When $a>b>c$ & $x>y>z$ , then :
$a+x>b+y>c+z$
$ax>by>cz$
These are always true (given Natural Numbers)

**Subtraction :**
Let $(a,b,c)=(303,202,101)$ & $(x,y,z)=(300,20,1)$
It is not true that :
$303-300>202-20>101-10$ , because we have $3 > 182 > 91$ , which is not true.

**Division :**
Let $(a,b,c)=(300,200,100)$ & $(x,y,z)=(100,2,1)$
It is not true that :
$300/100>200/2>100/1$ , because we have $3 > 2 > 100$ , which is not true.

In these Examples , 1 Part is true , the other Part is not true.
We can make Examples where Both Parts are true & Both Parts are not true.